# Can we create "Timeline" in highstock?

Tags: highcharts, timeline

I want to create "timline" view in highstock. Is it possible.? It is available in highchart. The code in highcharts is as below.

```
 $(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({

     chart: {
         type: 'columnrange',
         inverted: true
     },
 });
```

[Link of the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/VenomXLR/u3eWz/)

Comment: You can use columnrange as you have or [gantt](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart)

Comment: I want it in highstock with the "timeseries" navigator.

Comment: Navigator is available only for non inverted charts.